# How to add objects into scene from file

Tags: objects, scene

I would like to know how to add an object into a scene just by dragging the file .. Is there any addon for this feature or something??

Comment: Please explain what you saw that seems there could be an addon or something? This would help understanding what you want. Are you talking about the _Asset Browser_? Or do you specifically want to drag a complete file into Blender? Well, for the latter, just drag a file from the Windows explorer into the viewport. You then have the choice to either open the file completely, link to something from that file or append something in the current scene. Since every file contains multiple data blocks, you cannot simply drag a file to open a single object without choosing it manually from all contents.

Comment: HELPS A LOT THANKS